# iText how to create indivisible text

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I want to add signature to generating pdf file, but sometimes, depending on the amount of text signature is separated into two sides. I was thinking about this if I put it in an invisible signature square?

Signature:

```
Yours sincerely
John Kowalski
```

wrong result:

```
Yours sincerely
                Page1
---------------------
---------------------
                Page2
John Kowalski
```

How to create such algorithm?

Answer (score 2):

There are many different ways to achieve this.

One could create a `PdfTemplate`, add the text, wrap the template inside an `Image`, and add the `Image`.

One could create a `PdfPTable` with 1 column, 1 row, make sure rows aren't split in two, and add the table.

One could check the current Y position, calculate how much space is needed for the text, trigger `newPage()` if there's no sufficient space.

Etc...

Comment: sounds interesting, but how to do it? I want to add to the last page in the lower right corner. How do I know that this is the last page of the document?

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you, the developer of your application, don't know what is the last page of the document, how can anybody else know? You're the one who decides whether or not content is added after "Yours sincerely ...", aren't you?

Comment: I want to know which page is the last to be able to add a signature dynamically

Comment: That doesn't help. Maybe somebody else understands what you mean, but I give up.